# Updating records in a text file with php

Tags: php, html, record, updates

I'm using php to display records read from a text file which has space padded strings each with size 10. I opened the file unpacked it and displayed it in the text boxes until EOF is reached.
this is **code** i used:

```
<html>  
<head>
    <title>Read Records</title>
    <?php 
        $YourFile = "student.txt"; 
        $handle = fopen($YourFile,'r'); 
        $id = 0;
        while (!feof($handle)) {
            if ($s = fread($handle, 30)) {
                $readata = unpack("A10chars/A10int/A10inr",$s);
                $chars = $readata['chars'];
                $int = $readata['int'];
                $inr = $readata['inr'];

                echo "<input type=\"text\" id=\"chars$id\" name=\"name\" value=\"$chars\">";
                echo "<input type=\"text\" id=\"int$id\" name=\"name\" value=\"$int\">";
                echo "<input type=\"text\" id=\"inr$id\" name=\"name\" value=\"$inr\">";
                echo "<br>";
                $id = $id + 1;

            }
        }
    fclose($handle); 
?> 
</head>
```

Now if the user edit any records I need to keep track of the changes made and update it in the file. the ID of the elements are generated using the php code. How can find which is the record being edited??

Answer (score 1):

Here is the logic :

When you are reading from the file, you would need to remember the position of the first and last character read. If the user updates, then you would need to remove the text from the first to last position and then insert the new text in its place.

Although I'm not sure how you'd go about doing this.

Have you looked into SQLite ( http://www.sqlite.org/ ), it is a simple way to do the same thing you are trying to do. The DB file is kept local on your machine since SQLite does not get installed.